# C# Illusive Maths issue

Tags: c#, math

I am writing a program to calculate the amount of turf needed for a garden with a one meter border, and then find the total cost if the turf costs £10 per sq meter. This is the code I have so far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace _3._6
{
    public partial class frmTurfCalculator : Form
    {
        public frmTurfCalculator()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public float LengthFinal { get; private set; }
        public double Lengthvalue { get; private set; }
        public float WidthFinal { get; private set; }
        public double WidthValue { get; private set; }

        private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Lengthvalue = Convert.ToDouble(txtLength.Text);
            double LengthFinal = (Lengthvalue - 2);

            WidthValue = Convert.ToDouble(txtWidth.Text);
            double WidthFinal = (WidthValue - 2);

            double GardenArea = (WidthFinal * LengthFinal);
            double TurfCost = (10 * GardenArea);
            lblOutput1.Text = ("Amount of Turf (with 1m boundry): " + GardenArea);
            lblOutput2.Text = ("Total cost of turf = " + TurfCost + "£");
        }
    }
}
```

For some reason, whenever I run the (I used Width of 6m and Length of 6m) it comes up with a really weird result (16meters squared). This happens with different inputs, but for the sake of explanation I'm using 6m.

Thanks

Comment: What's a strange namespace (_3._6)

Comment: You can solve such problems by using the debugger to inspect what the program does at runtime.

Comment: And the result should be...?

Comment: Commented this on an answer, commenting here for visibility too: 
This is correct though right? He says a garden with a 1 meter border. Now, assuming this border surrounds the turf on all sides, a 6*6 garden will have a 4*4 area that needs turfing, so the answer should be 16m^2

Comment: Hahaha oh my god I'm such an idiot! Cant believe I didn't realize that! thanks

Comment: You shouldn't edit your question so that it doesn't match existing answers, and *never* just edit the entire thing away.  If you want to delete your question, that may be an option, although that also depends on the answers' scores.

Comment: @KaiMcClymont This question has been open for a very long time. If one of the answers solved your issue, please accept it as the valid answer to help others with similar issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is with these 2 lines of code:

```
double LengthFinal = (Lengthvalue - 2);

double WidthFinal = (WidthValue - 2);
```

You are subtracting 2 from width and length. So 6 * 6 becomes 4 * 4, giving you the result of 16.

If you set breakpoints and debugged through your code (or even just looked at your code), you would have seen this immediately.

Comment: On the plus side (or rather minus side), one can create turf to sell by having a garden where one dimension is less than 2m. :)

Comment: This is correct though right? He says a garden with a 1 meter border. Now, assuming this border surrounds the turf on all sides, a 6*6 garden will have a 4*4 area that needs turfing, so the answer should be 16m^2

Comment: @DavidWatts yeah that's the problem. 6*6 becomes 4*4. The problem was his understanding of what the code was doing. if he wants to enter 6*6 and get 36, he's going to have to edit the code. Not really sure why this got downvoted since it explained what the code was doing.

Comment: @user1666620 I feel bad you have been downvoted for pointing out the misunderstanding. Have an upvote

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe you have an issue. You state:

> I am writing a program to calculate the amount of turf needed for a garden with a one meter border

The values you are using for width and height are both 6. So you have a 6 * 6 garden, with a 1 meter border (Assuming the border surrounds all sides of the turf). That leaves you with a 4*4 area that needs turfing.

This leaves you with a remaining area to turf of 16 meters squared, which is the result you are getting. So the final value should be £160.